# Stop reading input in java without EOF

Tags: java, input, file-io, bufferedreader

In [this](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=673) question, how do i stop reading input? My program just keeps running, asking for more input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String src;

    while ((src = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String trgt = br.readLine();
       //do something
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String src;

while ((src = br.readLine()) != null) {
    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(src);
    if(!st.hasMoreTokens()) break;
    //YOUR LOGIC GOES HERE 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for a special string for instance END. When `trgt` equals to "END" then you can break the loop.

Comment: but the online judge wont accept that answer
input is provided by the judge, i cant change the input format.

Comment: So what will the judge provide to indicate there is no more input? I would assume it is an EOF, no? @utkarsh691-sopho

Answer (score 0):

As said @ihsan kocak you can look for a string like EXIT or QUIT.When you find the string just break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Set a specific word as a reading breaker. For example `stop`. If the user gives the input `stop` then the reading process will end. Here is an implementation example of this process:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String src;

    while ((src = br.readLine()) != null && !(src.equals("stop"))) {
        String trgt = src;
       //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Nested methods? And you're reading three times from the input stream ...

Comment: You still copied your method and the first two variables and you still read a second time. Both things are wrong.

Comment: Ok @Tom, now you are out of question's scope. Every code needs improvement, but this is not our case here. Nevertheless, i have changed the implementation is order to avoid repeatable readings. But lets just focus on user's question.

Comment: Ok, then let's do it easy: until this answer is obivously wrong/unhelpful, it deserves a downvote. And OPs question wasn't to get uncompilable code in an answer.

Comment: It was a copy paste problem which happened due to my rush. It is actually so simple!

Comment: And yet it needed three comments from me where I mention that until you noticed that.

Comment: Sometimes you focus on the tree, loosing the forest view!